Office365 auth on behalf of user
I have to migrate from app authentication to the "on behalf of user" one in my python code.
Previously I used code:
context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(
        client_id=app_principal['client_id'],
        client_secret=app_principal['client_secret'])

But now I was instructed to get a token like this:
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + authgraph['tenantid'] + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
body = {
    "client_id":authgraph['clientid'],
    "scope":authgraph['graphuserscopes'],
    "username": authgraph['username'],
    "password": authgraph['password'],
    "grant_type":"password",
    "client_secret":authgraph['clientsecret']
}
r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
data = json.loads(r.content)

return data['access_token']

I could not find a provider in the library that will require both client_secret and password.
Do I need to implement it manually?
